# Refractive index liquids: Why hard to buy?

Tags: optics

Does anyone know the refractive index suppliers? I've found Cargille Labs (which customer service is terrible so far but the liquids may actually be OK), but nothing else comparable. I'd like to have a set of liquids with the refractive index in the range of 1.3...1.4. Are they so hard to produce that almost nobody does it or am I missing something?

Comment: Given that you're basically just asking for shopping advice, I think this is off topic. But as far as I know, we haven't _explicitly_ discussed whether these sorts of questions belong here or not, so if anyone wants to make a case for it being on-topic, we can open a discussion in [chat] or on [meta]. I will be happy to reopen this if there is community support for it.

Comment: This doesn't seem much different than this to me: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7898/

Comment: Also if there actually is a reason that they are hard to produce I'm curious what it is

Comment: @zephyr: You mean what is the reason or what is the IR liquid?

Comment: @zephyr and others: I don't remember seeing that other question you linked to when it was first posted. Looking at it now, my impression is that the "Can you recommend a retail outlet for this source?" part is off topic. But there is another part, "What kind of broad spectrum source would you recommend?" that is probably on topic, and that saves it from being closed.